# Saving Items with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have been working that for a while now I think any help will be appreciated. Currently my app is using RecyclerView and I was wondering How do we save items using RecyclerView. For instance, when I add or remove an item in my application and when I close the app and open it after I notice that is not saving any items saved or added before even though I set up

```
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

inside my code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: first read what is the job of recycler view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot save items in Recyclerview. Its only meant for Listing out items in your UI.

What You should do is to **store data inside SQLite DB and show it in recyclerview in activities onResume or onCreate Callback**

Check [here](http://androidheight.blogspot.in/2015/11/sqlite-database-in-android-application.html) for SQLite and RecyclerView Implementation

Answer (score 0):

If your RecyclerView displays key value pairs, you can consider saving your data in SharedPreferences. This data will persist until you uninstall the app.  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html